# How to keep the class as numeric when using read.xlsx to import data with NA

Tags: r, excel, character, numeric, na

I was using `read.xlsx` in `openxlsx` package to import data from excel to R.

The code is in a form in the following way:

```
return <- simplify2array(read.xlsx(data,sheet="Return",cols =c(2:220)))
```

Some columns of the data have empty values and when it is imported into R using `read.xlsx`, the empty cells would be set as `NA`.

However, one problem arises: the class of all cells in the matrix become `"character"` rather than `"numeric"`.

I made a test of using `read.xlsx` to import data without empty values and the cells in the matrix in R have a class of `"numeric"`. It means that the cells with `NA` cause the class of all cells becoming `"character"`.

Since I would like to use the data to make some calculation, if the class is character, I would get the error of `"non-numeric argument to binary operator"`. If I use `as.numeric` on the matrix, the matrix would be transformed to a vector.

How to keep the class as numeric when using `read.xlsx` to import data with `NA`?

Comment: It is because you are wrapping with `simplify2array` which returns a matrix and matrix can have only a single class

Comment: I have tried to delete simplify2array but it does not work since data.frame also can have only a single class in one column. Since some rows in a column have number while others are NA, all cells become "character".

Comment: Can you use `na.strings=NA` and also use `read.csv/read.table` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it seems that read.csv/read.table could not solve the problem and the class is still `"character"`.

Comment: Then, please show a small reproducible example

Comment: After my testing, the problem arises from the large matrix. If I import a small data like `return <- simplify2array(read.xlsx(data,sheet="Return",cols =c(2:20),rows=c(2:20)))`, class(return[1,1]) would return `"numeric"`. But if I import the whole data which has 220 cols and 2500 rows, class(return[1,1]) would return `"character"`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Hope you will be able to crack it.